# Does the CPU Usage of a kivy app drop when creating an apk

Tags: python, android, kivy, cpu, game-development

I created a more or less complex kivy app. When I run it on my pc (which isn't the best but also isn't the worst) the CPU needs about 40% power for running it. I thought it was the fault of my code, but it needs even a bit more power when running the pong example in the kivy_venv. So my question is will this issue solve when creating an apk for play store or will it still need this much power?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing about making an APK that is expected to reduce cpu usage, but that much cpu usage shouldn't be necessary. I wonder if there's something you're doing to cause it, or perhaps you have found a bug.